# Make text box inside a div expand and shrink based on window size (div already does so)

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am pretty new to HTML/jQuery, and I am designing a portfolio site for a class.  I made a graphic that contains a box on the left where text should go.  I wanted to minimize scrolling for the user so I have made the divs containing the images resize with the window, and have also implemented a minimum size.  I am getting a little confused on how to do this with my text box now.  I am trying to create a div which is contained inside the background image divs in order to hold the text.  This text div needs to be positioned inside the box graphic and resize along with the images.  I tried using percentages for the margins but it doesn't work because as I resize the window, it becomes unaligned again.

[Here is the page.]

[Here is the CSS.]

Also, please keep in mind this is a work in progress and the graphics and animation will not stay exactly how they are!  If anyone can help me out, please let me know, and thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this jsfiddle and let me know if this is more of something like what you want?

html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>some | header | nav</header>
    <div class="content">
        <p>test text</p>
    </div>
    <footer> a &copy; symbol </footer>



</body>
</html>​
```

CSS:

```
body {
 background:gray;   
}
header {background:black; color:white}
footer {background:black; color:white}

.content {
    margin: 25px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VsKsQ/

I hope that helps.

Comment: I want the text to stay aligned within that box.  Just adding the width and height constraints doesn't contain it in the same spot the whole time.

Comment: as far as i could tell that box is part of  image of the background there was no div that had that styling. i will look again...

Comment: I'm sorry, it's kind of hard to tell, but I don't think that's it.  If you look at the first link and resize the window, you see how the background image resizes with the window?  I want the text content of the page to always be perfectly contained in that grey box on the image, even as the page is resized.  The text box needs to resize just like the background image.

Comment: looks like you figured it out.

Comment: Mostly haha.  It's not perfect, but it's the best I could figure out on my own.  Thank you for the help :)